# how to set a value from repositorylookup edit to specific column in gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

how do i set a value into a  gridview column `price` when i select a product ?
so i don't need to type it manually.

[image]

```
Dim repo_lookupedit_gv2 As New Repository.RepositoryItemLookUpEdit

  Public Sub load_product()
    Dim perintah As New SqlCommand
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        Using MyAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
            knk.MyConnection.Open()
            dt.Clear()
            With perintah
                .Connection = knk.MyConnection
                .CommandText = "select * from product"
                MyAdapter.SelectCommand = perintah
                MyAdapter.Fill(dt)
            End With
        End Using                    

        repo_lookupedit_gv2.DataSource = dt
        repo_lookupedit_gv2.ValueMember = dt.Columns("code").ToString
        repo_lookupedit_gv2.DisplayMember = dt.Columns("product").ToString
        repo_lookupedit_gv2.PopupWidth = 450

        gridview2.columns("product").columnedit = repo_lookupedit_gv2

        AddHandler repo_lookupedit_gv2.EditValueChanged, AddressOf repo_lookupedit_gv2_changed

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failed to load data product !")
    Finally
        knk.MyConnection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub GridView2_InitNewRow(sender As Object, e As InitNewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView2.InitNewRow
    Dim row As DataRow = GridView2.GetDataRow(e.RowHandle)
    row("qty") = 1
    row("price") = repo_lookupedit_gv2.Columns("price").ToString() \\\'it give me error
End Sub
```

[image]

iam also have tried

```
    Private Sub repo_lookupedit_gv2_changed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MsgBox(repo_lookupedit_gv2.Columns("price").ToString())
End Sub
```

which give me nothing

[image]

Comment: Have you also tried using `.Value`? As the error in picture is saying column `price` is in the wrong format.

Comment: there is no `.value`. it got `.valuemember` and i have tried that also. it give me an error `Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <code> in price Column.  Expected type is Decimal.` but if you look at the repository the value was not `price` but instead `code`

Answer (score 2):

**Refer this:**[GridControl - How to get a value from the in-place GridLookUpEdit editor's column and change a value in another grid column correspondingly](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q373602)

```
Private Sub repositoryItemGridLookUpEdit1_EditValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            Dim editor As GridLookUpEdit = TryCast(sender, GridLookUpEdit)
            Dim index As Integer = editor.Properties.GetIndexByKeyValue(editor.EditValue)
            If index < 0 Then
                Return
            End If

            Dim value As Object = (TryCast(editor.Properties.View.GetRow(index), DataRowView)).Row("Name")
            gridView2.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Name", value)
  End Sub
```

See the above example, You can get the editor Row or Class object depending upon which type of data source you bind with the repositoryitem control.

In you case you are binding it with data table then you will get `DataRowView` as in shown example. After that you can fetch the selected row column values and set it to the grid row cell values using the method `gridView2.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Name", value)`

References:
[How to get and set the GridLookUpEdit's value](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q575769)